# How to convert of a object into string?

Tags: apex, unit-test, query, code-coverage

```
@isTest static void test_deleteAddOnApplicant1(){
        Test.startTest();
         List<Applicant__c> appid = [select id from Applicant__c limit 1 ];

         String result = CF_ALL_Offers_CC.deleteAddOnApplicant(get(0).Applicant__c);
        Test.stopTest();
        
    }
```

I want to convert the id in `appid` into a string and store it in string variable result and then pass it to `deleteAddonApplicant` method. I am getting errors. Can someone please help me?

Comment: Hi Karan, do you mean serialize?

Comment: yes you can say. The deleteAddonApplicant method takes string as argument that's why.

Answer (score 4):

You can serialize the objects like below

```
String jsonStr = JSON.serialize(obj);
```

However, there is a syntax error in your code. You can access the list element either with array notation `appid[index]` or the get `appid.get(0)` method.

So do this.

```
String jsonStr = JSON.serialize(appid[0]);
String result = CF_ALL_Offers_CC.deleteAddOnApplicant(jsonStr);
```

Comment: thank you so much rahul

Answer (score 0):

Another option depending on what you are trying to achieve is to override the toString method. Every class in Apex inherits from class and they all have this method available.

```
public with sharing class Dollar extends Money{


    public Dollar(Integer amount){
        this.amount = amount;
        this.currencyType = 'Dollar';
    }

    public override Money times(Integer multiplier){
        return new Dollar(this.amount * multiplier);
    }
    public override String toString(){
        return  'Currency = ' + this.currencyType +
                ', Amount = ' + this.amount;
    }
}
```

running

```
Dollar dollar = new Dollar(5);
System.debug(dollar.toString());
```

Would return
|USER_DEBUG|[2]|DEBUG|Currency = Dollar, Amount = 5

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful if you included what errors you getting in your post, but it's likely because `appid` is not a collection of Ids, it's a collection of `Applicant__c` records. If you truly need just the Id from the record, then you can just do the below:

```
String result = CF_ALL_Offers_CC.deleteAddOnApplicant(get(0).Applicant__c.Id);
```